# Angular 11, :enter and :leave animation not working with *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-animations, angular11

I just started with Angular animations. And wan't to animate a *ngIf with it. Sadly it does't work :(. I don't get an error message. I tried several solutions from here, nothing worked. Also removing one of the animations doesn't change anything or removing one of the *ngIf-blocks entirely doesn't change anything. It just doesn't work, and there is also no error in the terminal or in the devtools visible.

Here the animations definition from the typescript.

```js
animations: [
  trigger('inOutPaneAnimation', [
    state('true', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
  state('void', style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
  transition(':enter', [animate('750ms ease-in-out')]),
  transition(':leave', [animate('600ms ease-in-out')]),
]),
trigger('inOutActiveItemAnimation', [
    state('true', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
  state('void', style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(100%)' })),
  transition(':enter', [animate('600ms ease-in-out')]),
  transition(':leave', [animate('750ms ease-in-out')]),
]),
```

The HTML looks like this:

```html
<div
  *ngIf="activeItem"
  [@inOutActiveItemAnimation]
  class="bt3-locations__active-item"
>
  <app-location-active-item
    [isSingleLocation]="isSingleLocation"
    [location]="activeItem"
    [showRouteLabel]="showRouteLabel"
  ></app-location-active-item>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!activeItem" [@inOutPaneAnimation] #paneContent>
  <div
    *ngTemplateOutlet="
      locations.data.length > 1 ? multipleGroups : group;
      context: { data: getGroups(), group: 0 }
    "
  ></div>
</div>
```

The BrowserAnimationsModule is imported, into the the parent module.

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { LocationItemComponent } from './location-item/location-item.component'; 
import { LocationsComponent } from './locations/locations.component';
import { LocationActiveItemComponent } from './location-active-item/location-active- 
item.component';
import { AccordionModule } from '../accordion/accordion.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      LocationsComponent,
    LocationItemComponent,
    LocationActiveItemComponent,
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule, AccordionModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
  exports: [],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how you create `:enter` and `:leave` animation

```js
trigger("inOutPaneAnimation", [
    transition(":enter", [
        style({ opacity: 0, transform: "translateX(-100%)" }), //apply default styles before animation starts
        animate(
            "750ms ease-in-out",
            style({ opacity: 1, transform: "translateX(0)" })
        )
    ]),
    transition(":leave", [
        style({ opacity: 1, transform: "translateX(0)" }), //apply default styles before animation starts
        animate(
            "600ms ease-in-out",
            style({ opacity: 0, transform: "translateX(-100%)" })
        )
    ])
])
```

You don't even need property binding `[]`, this is enough `@inOutPaneAnimation`

```html
<div *ngIf="!activeItem" @inOutPaneAnimation #paneContent>
...
</div>
```

[Read More Here](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#enter-and-leave-aliases)

Here is a [working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-sample-enter-and-leave-hdnawq)

**Note: Make sure to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` in main module.**

Comment: Sadly, doesn't work yet. That was the original way I followed, then I did fiddle with it a bit. But also with your code it doesn't work. May it be a problem that the animations don't work when *ngIf is not bound to a boolean? The class ng-trigger-inOutPaneAnimation is added, so I assume this is working.

Comment: @MarcelBührig Answer updated, Added working example

Comment: The BrowserAnimationsModule is imported in the main module. And we have other working code, which has animations. Just not :enter and :leave animations.

Comment: Your solution worked. What you didn't know, and couldn't know, that the top element was on ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom, then it is not working.

Comment: Interestingly, the opacity on this stackblitz doesn't seem to be working? I think it might need `opacity: '1'` instead?

Answer (score 2):

The solution, was fairly simple.

Make sure the ViewEncapsulation of your component is not set to ShadowDom. Then it is not working.

And also make sure to check @Sameer's answer. It is the right way to implement it.

Comment: That's good you fixed it yourself, I didn't know about that and there is no fix until now for this. Here is the [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25672)